# How to set justify center with Tr in chakra-ui?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I take a reference from official.

https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/table/usage

When I put an Image on `Td`, the other `Td` elements out of center.

[image]

I try to set `justifyContent={'center'}` on `Tr`, but it's not working.

Here is my code, all of the component are from `chakra-ui`

```
                    <TableContainer>
                        <Table size="sm">
                            <Thead>
                                <Tr>
                                    <Th>To convert</Th>
                                    <Th>into</Th>
                                    <Th isNumeric>multiply by</Th>
                                </Tr>
                            </Thead>
                            <Tbody>
                                <Tr bg={'pink'} justifyContent={'center'}>
                                    <Td>
                                        <Stack align={'center'} direction={'row'}>
                                            <Image
                                                height="48px"
                                                width="48px"
                                                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555041469-a586c61ea9bc?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1770&q=80"
                                                alt="Green double couch with wooden legs"
                                                borderRadius="lg"
                                            />
                                            <Text fontSize={'14px'} color={'gray.700'}>
                                                Test Test Test RTest
                                            </Text>
                                        </Stack>
                                    </Td>
                                    <Td>millimetres (mm)</Td>
                                    <Td isNumeric>25.4</Td>
                                </Tr>
                                <Tr>
                                    <Td>feet</Td>
                                    <Td>centimetres (cm)</Td>
                                    <Td isNumeric>30.48</Td>
                                </Tr>
                                <Tr>
                                    <Td>yards</Td>
                                    <Td>metres (m)</Td>
                                    <Td isNumeric>0.91444</Td>
                                </Tr>
                            </Tbody>
                            <Tfoot>
                                <Tr>
                                    <Th>To convert</Th>
                                    <Th>into</Th>
                                    <Th isNumeric>multiply by</Th>
                                </Tr>
                            </Tfoot>
                        </Table>
                    </TableContainer>
```

Next.js project about css reset code, I think I have add tbody, thead, tr, th, td should be fine.

```
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

In `<ChakraProvider />,` I just add breakpoints and fonts setting:

```
const fonts = {
    heading: `'Open Sans', sans-serif`,
    body: `'Raleway', sans-serif`,
};

// 2. Update the breakpoints as key-value pairs
const breakpoints = {
    base: '0px',
    sm: '320px',
    md: '768px',
    lg: '960px',
    xl: '1200px',
    '2xl': '1536px',
};

// 3. Extend the theme
const theme = extendTheme({ breakpoints, fonts });

return (
  <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
    <MyAppComponent />
  </ChakraProvider>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chakra UI's `<Tr>` component isn't a flex or grid container, so `justifyContent` shouldn't have any effect on alignment. Try replacing `justifyContent` with `verticalAlign` instead.

```js
<Tr bg={'pink'} verticalAlign={'middle'}>
```

For convenience, here's a [CodeSandbox playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-breeze-vhxpzl?file=/src/index.tsx) with the provided use case.

Comment: Thanks for your help, `verticalAlign={'middle'}` is not wokring on my code. I check your CodeSandbox code is working, so I just try to copy and paste on my React project is still not working, that's weird.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about your project setup? Are you using a framework like Next, Remix, or Gatsby? Are there any other stylesheets being imported into the app outside of Chakra UII? Are you using any Chakra UI theme customizations? Anything special about the ChakraProvider setup? 

Sometimes other stylesheets can conflict with the base Chakra theme. Sometimes styles have to be set on Td instead of Tr. It depends on each situation.

Any additional detail you can provide is valuable for those looking to help.

Comment: According your suggestion set on Td instead of Tr, I find out just set `verticalAlign={'middle'}` on `<Td>` is working. I also update my question about my project setting, I have a reset file includes tr, th, td, thead, tbody. Still can't figure it out why. Fell free answer me again when you have time. Your response help me a lot, thank you very much.